# PGFPLOTS coordinate filtering as a style?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am using pgfplots to make plots for my thesis, and I have many scatter plots that I want to have consistent formatting.  I am controlling the shape and color of the scatter plot marks with two columns (from external files loaded through `\pgfplotstableread`) that have consistent names across the many input files.

So far, my solution is to use one as to define `scatter/classes` and to use the other to filter.  This has worked fine, but I would like to have the filter parameters specified as a style, rather than needing to repeat the filter code on every `\addplot` command.

What is working:

```
\documentclass{article}               

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x y color shape
1 3 a 0
2 6 b 0
3 5 a 1
4 4 b 1
5 9 a 0
6 1 b 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\datafile

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[x filter/.code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{shape}\of{\datafile}
    \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=0
    \else
    \def\pgfmathresult{}
    \fi},only marks, scatter, scatter src=explicit symbolic,  scatter/classes={
a={blue},%
b={red}%
},mark=o] table[x=x,y=y, meta=color] {\datafile};
\addplot[x filter/.code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{shape}\of{\datafile}
    \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=1
    \else
    \def\pgfmathresult{}
    \fi},only marks, scatter, scatter src=explicit symbolic, scatter/classes={
a={blue},%
b={red}%
},mark=square] table[x=x,y=y, meta=color] {\datafile};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I can't just plug the `x filter` code as it is into a style, since it uses the name of the table (which changes).  I've tried the [discard if not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98003/filter-rows-from-a-table) style, but it doesn't work with `\pgfplotstableread`

Can I put the filtering code in a style and modify it so it automatically gets the correct table (being used for everything else in the plot)?

I'm aware that I could approach the entire problem differently by using `\pgfplotstableset` to create a new column in the table that has (somehow) concatenated the color and shape, and then have (2x2 in the example) 4 different scatter classes.

Comment: I hadn't realized that styles took an argument like that.  That isn't as great as being able to automatically get the table name, but it certainly helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until a table-name aware solution arrives you can create your own style to reduce the repetition.

```
\documentclass{article}               

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x y color shape
1 3 a 0
2 6 b 0
3 5 a 1
4 4 b 1
5 9 a 0
6 1 b 1
\end{filecontents}


\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\datafile

\pgfplotsset{
mystyle/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{shape}\of#1
        \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=#2\relax
        \else
        \def\pgfmathresult{}%
        \fi
    },
    only marks, scatter, scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    scatter/classes={
        a={blue},%
        b={red}%
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mystyle={\datafile}{1},mark=o] table[x=x,y=y, meta=color] {\datafile};
\addplot[mystyle={\datafile}{0},mark=square] table[x=x,y=y, meta=color] {\datafile};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an ugly hack, you can then define a new function that includes the whole `\addplot....` where you can change the table name in both places.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach seems to be leading me to 'TeX capacity exceeded' problems (for the actual document).  I wasn't seeing it when the filtering was in each addplot line.  This is happening even with tikzexternalize.

Comment: @ackey It's strange indeed. Especially when everything is working with the explicit options. Maybe my cook-up isn't that innocent looking behind the scenes. Is it working with mildly large files or just doesn't work even with 50 items?

Comment: It is working now.  I introduced some bugs when I set up the styles, but finally have them worked out now.  Your answer is good, and I'll select it if no one has a method for the name-aware solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to pass shape as an argument? I can't seem to be able to pass an extra argument and get this to work.