# remove row from pgfplotstable macro

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I've got to a point where I have some data stored in a pgfplotstable macro.  I want to remove a row from that macro (a line where some data is missing) and then further process the remaining data (doing some calculations) before plotting it with pgfplots.  What I think would work would be if I could create a new macro containing all of the original data, omitting the row where data is missing.  Is this possible?  Or is there a better way?  This is a simplified version of the situation I'm in.  In this case I would want to remove the row `2,2,,`.  There may be multiple lines with missing data, and I don't necessarily know exactly which ones they are.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  a,b,c,d
  1,1,1,1
  2,2,,
  3,3,3,3
}\data
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\data}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x=a,y=b]{\data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer and code provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436023/110494) seems to do what I need.

Here's a sample file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,pgfplotstablefilter}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  a,b,c,d
  1,1,1,1
  2,2,,
  3,3,3,3
  4,4,4,4
  5,5,,
}\data
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/table/col sep=comma}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\data}
\pgfplotstablefilter[c unequal {}]{\data}{\newdata}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\newdata}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x=a,y=b]{\newdata};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alas, `\pgfplotstablevertcat` does not support options.  BTW, this assumes you know what rows to remove.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  a,b,c,d
  1,1,1,1
  2,2,,
  3,3,3,3
}\data
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablesave[skip rows between index={1}{2}]{\data}{filename}% create new file
\pgfplotstableread{filename}\data% read new file
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\data}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x=a,y=b]{\data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'd missed `\pgfplotstablesave` in the manual. I wonder if there is any way to do this if I don't know where the missing data might be?  (Which could conceivably be more than one line.) I worry that with this approach I might get the index wrong one way or another.

Comment: You can search using \pgfplotstablegetelem, although I'm not sure how to distinguish missing data.  You can remove multiple rows using \pgfplottableset[skip rows between...] in a loop.