# Adding jitter to a straight line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have found a post about: [How to add a jitter to a scatter plot with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44547/how-to-add-a-jitter-to-a-scatter-plot-with-pgfplots). I'd like to add jitter to a straight green line to recreate this graph.[image].

Would this be the best way do you think? Also are the arrows decorations?

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-4,xmax=+0, ymin=-0.5,ymax=4.5, axis lines=left] 

\addplot[draw=green, mark=none, ultra thick, domain=-4.0:-0.1,
         samples=100] 
    {2}
    node [midway, above right] {\small $\bar{U}$ Time-average velocity}; 

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps make this in paint?

Comment: No, perhaps put a clear image for what you mean for _jitter to a straight green line_: this might clarify a bit what you're wondering to everybody. :)

Comment: Just apply the theory of efficient markets to the green line, and on the basis of no-arbitrage, it should converge with the fair value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This approach is really similar to vrleboss' suggestion, but in order to fit the arrow for the fluctuating velocity, we'll need to simulate autocorrelated noise (or try lots of realisations of the uncorrelated noise).

Here I've used a product of two cosine functions as the base function, and then added random noise on top:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-4,xmax=+0, ymin=-0.5,ymax=4.5, axis lines=left,
    clip=false] 

\addplot[draw=black, mark=none, ultra thick, domain=-4.0:-0.1,
         samples=2] 
    {2}
    node [right] {\small $\bar{U}$ Time-average velocity}; 
\addplot[draw=red, mark=none, ultra thick, domain=-4.0:-0.1,
         samples=100] 
    {2+0.8*cos(x*300)*cos(x*50)+rand/5}
    node [red, right] {\small $U$ Instantaneous velocity}
    coordinate [pos=0.25] (point); 
\draw [ultra thick, blue, latex-latex] (point) -- (point|-{axis cs:0,2}) node [pos=0, anchor=-160] {$u'$ Fluctuating velocity};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To have an even nicer curve add the `smooth` option to `\addplot[...]`

Answer (score 5):

I would use the `rand` function. The decoration produces non-causal curves.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-4,xmax=+0, ymin=-0.5,ymax=4.5, axis lines=left] 

\addplot[draw=green, mark=none, ultra thick, domain=-4.0:-0.1,
         samples=100] 
    {2}
    node [midway, above right] {\small $\bar{U}$ Time-average velocity}; 

\addplot[purple,ultra thick, domain=-4.0:-0.1,samples=50] {0.5*rand+2};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]